# Honeypots in review queues are potentially unforgiving to misclicks?

Tags: support, review

I encountered my first honeypot review today. (Not linking to it here, but I can if it's needed.) I did take the correct action on it, which in this case (as in several possible situations) was a multi-step process. However, the "congratulations, you passed" message appeared immediately upon the first step.

Obviously this is a time-saver in that no extra reviewer time is wasted on a non-actionable review. However, it got me thinking about the potential for misclicks. That is, if the correct action is to flag the post, but I misclick and hit Edit, the system will immediately consider me to have failed the audit. (Insert snark about "the poor mouse-bound luser" here.)

Is the weight of honeypot reviews light enough to absorb the "cost" of one mistake, or is this something that could use altering? (I'm confident enough in my reviewing that I'm not concerned regardless of the answer, but it would be nice to be sure that this is status-by-design.)

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's probably just whether you give crap posts the "Looks good" review.

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/151367) implies that *passing the test* means *not reviewing a post positively*: "*If a user reviews such a post positively, they are presented with a message that they didn't pass and encouraged to pay more attention in the future. If a user passes the test, they are informed that they passed and thanked for their time and feedback.*" [Here's also an additional indicator that taking any critical action means you pass](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158733/151367).

Comment: The team's aware of this. Not much to do about it at the current stage, but the usual robo reviewer will just click their way through and don't care to move their mouse to the flag button.

Comment: I see. That answers the question then.